# MPI and stdin overheading?

Tags: c++, mpi, overhead

I am coding a program in C++ MPI but when passing a large file as `stdin` I am facing the problem that the threads are not seeing the same `stdin` information.

More elaborated, I am passing as standard input a list of input files, which is then stored in a `vector<string>`:

```
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
int CORES, thread;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&CORES);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&thread);
stringstream tline;
int count = 0;
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);){
    tline << line << " ";
    count++;
    }

vector<string> args(count,"");
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    tline >> args[i];

cout << thread << " " << count << endl; //each thread outputs the number of input files it received
```

My problem is that this gives different numbers for different threads. For instance, after passing a file of 10 000 lines, I get:

```
5 9464
6 9464
3 9464
4 9464
1 9554
2 9554
0 10000
7 9464
```

Is it because of some overheading? How can I avoid that?

Comment: We need a fuller code sample to really say anything. I imagine the problem is the two for loops are not syncronised so some of the variables get updated before they propagate to other threads. Also this is in no way an overhead problem.

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu : I reduced the code to the subset showing an issue. I also substracted the preprocessor instructions and the main function initialization, which I don't think are relevant. May I ask what do you mean by the loops are unsynchronized? Aren't they just executed locally  and sequentially by each thread?

Comment: Ok, so is this only the MPI thread code? In that case I believe the problem is in cin, as there is only one cin from which you can consume. How many lines in total are you expecting?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu 10 000 lines. How could I duplicate the cin?

Comment: There are no threads anywhere in this code, and solutions (or descriptions of the problem) that involve contention or race conditions between threads are mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so basically your problem is that you all your threads are consuming lines from **cin** and they race. Even though **cin** gives some guarantees for thread safeness in general you are not always certain what you would get. Check this thread: [How do scanf(), std::cin behave on multithreaded environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844239/how-do-scanf-stdcin-behave-on-multithreaded-environment)

Solution: Don't use CIN? Use a file and have each thread open the file on its own with a filehandle. If you really want to use **cin** then have one thread from MPI read **CIN** and broadcast it to other threads and then they can whatever they want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution proposal. I went for the second one, and broadcasted it using `MPI_Bcast` though I had to use intermediate `char *`. I am really new to MPI (started today to be honest), should I use MPI_Barrier instead of `sleep` calls to make the threads wait for eachother?

Comment: You should't really be using sleep in multithreaded environment. Always barriers, this is proper synchronization.